# Where to start with ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I am very clearly missing something.  I want to start setting up a web server, and I've already successfully set up nginx and PHP.  However, I used black magic incantations from the Internet and have no idea how or why any of what I did works. Unfortunately, I also want to set up Ruby on Rails, and it turns out that any tutorials on the web just tell me: you need X so type Y.  What is more concerning is that most of the tutorials use different technologies and entirely different linux commands.  Is there some distilled, basic setup that can help me to learn how to both set up RoR and also to learn how to get familiar with the core commands of Ubuntu so I can use it well?

Comment: https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04 is one we use every so often here. And yes it IS a lot of typing commands.

Comment: Thanks.  I think what I was really getting at is a bit different.  I don't mind typing in the commands (I *am* working with Linux after all), and I have a small working knowledge of some commands.  What I feel is totally lacking from most tutorials (including that one) is an explanation of what all of it does.  For example, in that tutorial, it has "using rbenv (recommended)", well, why is it recommended?  Also, "rbenv users need to run rbenv rehash after installing bundler.", again, why?  Is there a tutorial that starts by saying "we need all of these things, so learn them first here?"

Comment: doubt it ;-) most "tutorials" don't explain anything and are just "typing instructions" :-P

Comment: Haha, then how do you learn all of this stuff?  Every time I look for something I find ten tutorials, none of which use the same technologies and all of which are JUST slightly different enough from my situation to make my life hard.  Have I missed something fundamental?

Comment: investigate each command on its own :X Yes, a lot of work. But it will pay out in the feature ;)

Comment: For some of the more idiomatic things (like `rbenv` in Ruby and `virtualenv` in Python), people are trying to get you into quite complicated but *best* practices. You're not wrong to question it but until you have some experience with you, you might have to take some things on faith :) You simply won't appreciate some things until you start doing things in a particular way (eg having multiple sites with separate environments, or doing system upgrades).